# How do I get rid of nvidia xserver?

Tags: nvidia

How can I get rid of Nvidia Xserver?
I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-xserver
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is it a laptop/desktop? What video card do you have and what actual issues arise?

Answer (score 1):

> sudo apt-get purge
>
> This command completely removes a package and the associated
>   configuration files. Configuration files residing in ~ are not usually
>   affected by this command.

This command should do the job just fill in nvidea-xserver. Command below.

> sudo apt-get purge nvidea-xserver

Bill

Answer (score 0):

This way may be helpful. 
$ sudo dpkg -P $(dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver | awk '{print $2}')   
$ sudo apt autoremove 
$ sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau 
Then, reboot.

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-uninstall-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux